# determine the limit points and the isolated points of each of the following sets.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to determine the limit points and the isolated points of each of the following sets. Below is what I am thinking, but am I correct for each of the following sets?

**a)**$\lbrace 1 - \frac{(-1)^n}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\rbrace$

$a_n = \lbrace 1 - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\rbrace$

Since $a_n$ converges to 1, the set has only one limit point 1, but every point of the set is an isolated point.

**b)**$\lbrace (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\rbrace$

$a_= (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}$

$a_1= (-1)^1 + \frac{1}{1} = 0$

$a_2= (-1)^2 + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \frac{1}{2}$

$a_3= (-1)^3 + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{-2}{3}$

$a_4= (-1)^4 + \frac{1}{4} = 1 \frac{1}{4}$

$a_5= (-1)^5 + \frac{1}{5} = \frac{-4}{5}$

$a_6= (-1)^6 + \frac{1}{6} = 1 \frac{1}{6}$

$a_7= (-1)^7 + \frac{1}{7} = \frac{-6}{7}$

If n is even, then it converges to 1.

If n is odd, then it converges to -1.

So, the limit points are (-1, 1). But are there any isolated points? I don't think there are any, but I'm not sure.

**c)**$(0,1)$  $\cup$ $\lbrace 2 \rbrace$

$[0,1]$ are limit points and $2$ is an isolated point

**d)**$\mathbb{N}$

There are no limit points and there are no isolated points.

**e)** $ \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$

There are no limit points, but every point is an isolated point

**f)** $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$

$[0,1]$ are limit points and there are no isolated points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us reiterate the meanings of limit and isolated points :

> A limit point of  a set is such that every neighborhood of that point intersects the set at a point other than the limit point itself.
>
> An isolated point is one such that there is a neighborhood around the point, in which no point of the set, other than the isolated point itself is contained. (In short, not a limit point).

In  that respect, $a$ seems fine to me.

In $b$,  the limit points are correct, and you can check that the isolated points of the set are those that are *not* limit points : in short, the whole of the set is in fact made of isolated points (you can design neighborhoods to satisfy the isolated condition, I leave you to do this).

$c$ looks fine to me.

In $d$, you are correct about there being no limit points, but then if you take $n \in \mathbb N$, then a ball of radius say $0.25$ around $n$ doesn't contain any natural numbers, so $\mathbb N$ *consists entirely* of isolated points.

In $e$, we have to be more careful.

Let $x$ be any real number. By a result that we know, we can find an irrational number arbitrarily close to $x$.(If you do not, then reply back)

That is to say, $\mathbb R$ is in fact the set of limit points of $\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q$. (Of course, this doesn't give any space for isolated points)

f) is correct.

If you are unconvinced, do reply back.